# Сравнение списка и словаря на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список и словарь, нужно сравнить значение списка со словарем и в случае совпадения значения вызвать функцию из словаря. Нужно сделать это циклом. Подскажите как это сделать?

```
def max():
    x = 5
    return x

def min():
    y = 10
    return y

ex{
  "xx": sum(),
  "yy": min(),
  }

a = ["xx", "yy"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых

```
ex = {
  "xx": sum,
  "yy": min,
}
```

Во-вторых

```
for i in a:
    if i in ex:
        ex[i]()
```

Или короче

```
for i in a:
    ex.get(i, lambda: None)()
```

Comment: Ошибка в вашем решении: in <module>
    ex.get(i, lambda: None)()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: @Каролина со всей возможной внимательностью посмотрите чем "во-первых" в моём примере отличается от вашего объявления словаря.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло

Comment: @Каролина [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Отметила как решение.